# Click on OpenLayers Map through layer

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openstreetmap

I have a map included on my page. There's also a transparent div, positioned on top of the map (with CSS).

Is it possible to **drag** the map through this transparent layer? The layer should not move, just the map underneath it.

Dragging the map outside the window is possible (see http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/examples/document-drag.html), but I want to **start dragging on the transparent layer**. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: is it mandatory to keep the div through the drag event? Because probably by removing the div temporary from the DOM and cache it in an object as soon the onclick event has been fired, and put it back to the DOM (from the cached object) as soon the onclick event has been finished, could work?

Comment: Try using [this technique][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680429/click-through-a-div-to-underlying-elements

Comment: @Daxcode I need to see the div all the time, removing the div is not an option.

Comment: @capdragon Thank you, that should do the trick.